# flashdata does not display form_validation errors

Tags: codeigniter, session

Previously I used OpenServer and I developed small log-in application using CodeIgiter and everything was working very well. But then due to some reasons I changed the server to Xampp and I copied all the controllers, views, model, and database to xammp server. And I brought all necessary changes in the config file, and autoload file. But when running from there I get many Fatal error. In addition the form_validation errors which i set it through flash-data() are not displayed.

could you please help me in this regards?

**Home Controller**

```
<?php
 class Home extends CI_Controller 
  {

   public function index ()
    {
        $data['main_view']= "home_view";
        $this->load->view('Layouts/main',$data);
    }
   }
?>
```

**Users Controller**

class Users extends CI_Controller
 {

```
    public function show()
    {

        $this->load->model('user_model');           
        $data['reslt']= $this->user_model->get_users(3);
    //  $this->load->view('user_view',$data);   
        foreach( $data['reslt'] as $objec)
        {
            echo $objec->Username;

        }
    }

    public function addUser()
    {

        $uname="Mursal";
        $upass="Not good for you";
        $this->load->model('user_model');    
        $this->user_model->create_user(['username'=>$uname,
                                        'UserPassword'=>$upass],$id);
    }


    public function updateUser()
    {

        $id=3;
        $uname="Mursal";
        $upass="Not good for you";
        $this->load->model('user_model');    
        $this->user_model->update_users(['Username'=>$uname,
                                        'UserPassword'=>$upass],$id);
    }

    public function deleteUsers($id)
    {

        $this->load->model('user_model');   
        $this->user_model->delete_user($id);
    }

    public function login()
    {
            //echo $_POST["username"];

        //echo $this->input->post('username');
        $this->load->model('user_model');   

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confrm_pass','Confirm Password','trim|required|matches[password]');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==false)
        {
            $data=array(
                'errors'=>validation_errors()
            );

            $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
            redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {

            $name=$this->input->post('username');
            $pass=$this->input->post('password');

            $userid=$this->user_model->log_in($name,$pass);

            if($userid)
            {
                $usrdata=array(

                    'user_name'=>$name,
                    'user_pass'=>$pass,
                    'loged_in'=>true
                    );  

                $this->session->set_userdata($usrdata);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success','You are now logged in');

                $data['main_view']="admin_view";
                $this->load->view('Layouts/main',$data);

                //redirect('home/index');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed','Sorry');
                redirect('home/index');

            }

        }

    }


    public function log_out()
    {

        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('home/index');
    }   

 }
?>
```

**User Model**

class User_model extends CI_Model
{

```
    public function log_in($name,$pass)
    {
            $this->db->where('Username',$pass);
            $this->db->where('UserPassword',$pass);

            $reslts=$this->db->get('users');

            if($reslts->num_rows()==1)
            {
                return $reslts->row(0)->ID;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;

            }
    }
 }
?>
```

**main view**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container">
 
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  <?php $this->load->view('users/Login_view');?>
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-9">
  <?php $this->load->view($main_view); ?>   
 </div>
 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**home_view**

```html
<h1>Hello, from home_view</h1>

<p class="bg-success">
 <?php if($this->session->flashdata('login_success')):?>

  <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('login_success'); ?>

 <?endif;?> 
</p>


<p class="bg-danger">
 <?php if($this->session->flashdata('login_failed')):?>
  <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('login_failed'); ?>

 <?php endif;?>


</p>
```

**Admin view**

```html
<h1>Admin View </h1>
```

**Login view**

Flash data errors should be displayed here,if you users violets form validation rules,but it does not work.

```html
<?php if($this->session->userdata('loged_in')): ?>

 <h2>Log Out</h2>
 <?php echo form_open('users/log_out');?>
 
 <p>
 <?php if($this->session->userdata('user_name')):?>
 <?php echo "You are logged in as " . $this->session->userdata('user_name');?>
 <?php endif;?>
 </p>
 
 <div class="form-group">
  <?php $data=array('name'=>'btnsbmt',
         'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
         'value'=>'Log out'
      );?>
  <?php echo form_submit($data);?>
 </div>


 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php else:?>

<h1>Log In form</h1>
<?php $attributes=array('ID'=>'login_form', 'class'=>'form_horizontal'); ?>

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')):?>

<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors'); ?>


<?php endif;?>

<?php echo form_open('users/login',$attributes); ?>

<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_label('User Name:');?>

<?php  $data=array(

  'class'=>'form-control',
  'Name'=>'username',
  'placeholder'=>'Enter Your Name');?>

<?php echo form_input($data);?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <?php echo form_label('Password:'); ?>

 <?php $data=array(
   'class'=>'form-control',
   'Name'=>'password',
   'placeholder'=>'Enter Your Password'
  );

  ?> 
<?php echo form_password($data); ?>  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <?php echo form_label('Confirm Password');?>

 <?php $data=array(
  'class'=>'form-control',
  'name'=>'confrm_pass',
  'placeholder'=>'Confirm Your Password',
  );?>

 <?php echo form_password($data);?>



</div>
<div class="form-group">

 <?php $data=array(
  'value'=>'Log In',
  'name'=>'btnSb',
  'class'=>'btn btn-primary'

  ); ?>
 <?php echo form_submit($data);?>
</div>

<?php echo form_close();?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: add relevant code only. Not entire code. its hard to understand where is it

Comment: https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. FYI, I am new to web programming and to CodeIgniter. the reason I uploaded all files because I thought that may be I had missed something in any of these and i hadn't been able to find it out. Now could you please help me why I am getting these errors? the url you added is useful thanks, but I want to know what the  reason is

Comment: Where you have loaded the session library?? I can't find it in your code. Make sure you have auto loaded it or loaded it in your controller.

Comment: I did that in auto load file

Answer (score 0):

**Its placed in controller**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {       
$errors = validation_errors();
           $this->session->set_flashdata('form_error', $errors);
           $this->load->view('Your View page');
}
```

**Its placed in your view page**

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('form_error')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('form_error');?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this it will help to you..!